# A lexical analyzer for SPDH

Tags: protocols, analyzer

I need some help to write a lexical analyzer for the protocole spdh.
Please can you give me some ideas: from where I have to begin to write the grammar of such protocol?!

Spdh defines the structure of request and response messages exchanged between an electronic payment terminal and the server of the bank.

Thank you

Comment: You might like to provide some information about what this protocol is.

Comment: A simple web search revealed no particular information about the protocol. Do you have a web link to some detailed info? What is your current experience with writing compilers? Do you know any of the usual tools such as lex/yacc, antlr? What is your target language? Recursive descent?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever write a compiler.this is my first experience with such programs! I may use javacc.I don't know for the recursive descent I didn't decide yet becauz I'm still reading about compiler theory.
So what parts I ve to focus in to write my analyzer?